# animate background color of multiple TextViews

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, textview

I have some `TextViews` inside my `Activity` that contains some text, and i would like to animate `background color` for all textviews at the same time.

Animation should be a `fade` in from current textviews background color to another color, for example red, and fade out from red to default textview color.

It's possible to do it?

Comment: use `ObjectAnimator`with " backgroundColor" property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one solution could be using a TransactionDrawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/start_drawable" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/end_drawable" />
</transition>
```

where `start_drawable` and `end_drawable` are shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/start_color"/>
</shape>
```

at runtime,

```
TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) textView.getBackground();
transition.startTransition(duration);
```

With the `ObjectAnimator`, thanks to @pskink to poin it out,

```
final ObjectAnimator animaor = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(textView, "backgroundColor", new ArgbEvaluator(), startColor, endColor);
animaor.setDuration(300);
animaor.setRepeatCount(2);
animaor.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
animaor.start();
```

`ObjectAnimator` and `ArgbEvaluator` require api level 11

Comment: but in this way i need to call twice  this function for each TextViews, one for make background go from startcolor to end color, and another one for make background go from end color to start color again

Comment: *from end color to start color again*, you can call `reverseTransition(duration)`. About the first part of your comment, you will have to do it in any case

Comment: does android take care of start reverseTransition when startTransition is over?

Comment: i've put a timer with same duration of transition, and on timer end, i start reverseTransition